# Animating a line plot and saving it as an avi movie in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to animate a line plot from a saved vector and save it as an avi file in Matlab. The code below can do it, but it does not capture the axis  (numbers on the axis etc.) and does not show the legend. How can I fix this issue? Attached a screenshot from the movie.

```
vidObj = VideoWriter('OneWeekJune.avi');
vidObj.Quality = 100;
open(vidObj);

h = animatedline;
axis([min,max,ymin,ymax])
xlabel('Time (minute)')
ylabel('Demand')
legend('Demand in June')
grid on
x = 1:7*1440;
y = [Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7];
for k = 1:10:length(x)
    addpoints(h,x(k),y(k));
    drawnow 
    currFrame = getframe;
       writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
end

close(vidObj);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `currFrame = getframe(gcf);`

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html

> `F = getframe(fig)` captures the figure identified by fig. Specify a figure if you want to capture the entire interior of the figure window, including the axes title, labels, and tick marks. The captured movie frame does not include the figure menu and tool bars.

Comment: is there a way to show the values that are being animated on the screen?